# How to pass a JPEG image to another activity using bundle?

Tags: android, image, uri, bundle, jpeg

I'm now writing an app using android studio. In the main activity, I wrote a function to take a photo by using camera, then I want to pass this photo to the second activity. In the second activity, I want to upload this photo to a web API, and the type of the uploaded image has to be "JPEG".

I'm not sure I should use bundle or not. Or should I use "URI"? But when I call this:

```
URI photo_uri = photo.toURI();
```

There would be some problem. I couldn't run it. How can I fix this? This is what I wrote now, I use bundle:

```
// photo -> photo_uri, "photo.toURI()" doesn't work
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("URI", photo_uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

And how can I receive the data(in JPEG type) in another activity?

Answer (score 1):

You can send the file or uri path to second activity. After getting file or uri path you can convert that path into the file and upload it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Android docs about using the camera](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics), there you have how to get the `Uri`, you must **NEVER** try to share the Bitmap itself.

About passing data between activities, you should use the `Bundle` so check this doc about [Parcelables and Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles) which is the way to share data.

Regards!